# Vue list rending with dynamic css property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a carousel-like list of items (like those iOS native date/time pickers), which could be shifted up or down.

The position of each item is based on `top` property from a model, that eventually gets assigned to each list item element with absolute positioning.

I managed to make it work in one direction, so if you press 'go up', it functions exactly as I wanted (you can check it out in the snippet below). On the other hand, when I use the same code for another direction (except I switch the `.pop()` function to `.shift()` and `.unshift()` to `.push()`) it works differently, specifically item values get reassigned, but nothing moves.

What I noticed is that in the second case list items get rendered from scratch for some reason, despite the item keys. Thus, coordinate transition doesn't happen.

What can I do to make this mechanism work in both directions? Feel free to take look at the snippet I prepared:

```js
Vue.component('list-component', {
  template: '#list-component',
  name: 'list-componet',
  data() {
   return {
     model: [],
      activeIndex: null,
      itemHeight: 56,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    shiftWheel(direction) {
      if (direction === 'up') {
        const value = this.model[0].value - 1;

        this.model.map((v) => {
          v.top += this.itemHeight;
        });

        this.model.pop();
        this.model.unshift({
          value,
          top: -this.itemHeight
        });

      } else {
        const value = this.model[this.model.length - 1].value + 1;

        this.model.shift();

        this.model.forEach((v) => {
          v.top -= this.itemHeight;
        });
        this.model.push({
          value,
          top: this.itemHeight * 5
        });
      }
   }
  },
  mounted() {
    const quantity = 5 + 2;
  
    this.top = -56;

    const currentYear = moment().year;
    const toTheSides = Math.floor(quantity / 2);

    this.activeIndex = quantity - toTheSides - 1;

    const start = moment().clone().subtract(toTheSides, 'Y');

    this.model = Array(quantity).fill().map((v, i) => {
      const value = start.clone();
      start.add(1, 'Y');
      return {
        value: value.year(),
        top: i * this.itemHeight - this.itemHeight
      };
    });
  }
});

new Vue({ 
    el: '#app'
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 280px;
  width: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.md-wheel-item {
  padding: 16px 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out;
  will-change: top;
  &.is-active {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="list-component">
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
     <div v-for="(item, iIndex) in model"
    :key="item.value"
       class="md-wheel-item"
       :class="{'is-active': iIndex === activeIndex}"
       :style="{height: itemHeight + 'px', top: item.top + 'px'}">
       {{ item.value || item }}
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
     <button @click.prevent="shiftWheel('up')">Go up</button>
     <button @click.prevent="shiftWheel('down')">Go down</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="content">   
      <list-component></list-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a difficult one for sure. I recommend looking into vue's `transition-group`s for this particular use case as they might be better suited for what you want to do: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

Comment: @b-fleming, It is indeed a way to solve it, but I am still interested to make it the way I describe above. btw, here is a fiddle I've made using `transition-group` as you proposed: https://jsfiddle.net/o_voloshin/mf5svm82/1/

Comment: @b-fleming you were completely right. Reading the github issue (https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4834) it seems like `transition-group` is my only way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this github issue (github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4834) as a reference it looks like I just have to use `transition-group`:

> They are not re-created (items), but moved by insertBefore. And if an element with transition is moved during the transition the transition is interrupted. The key ensures the elements end up in the correct position in the DOM when all manipulations are done, but doesn't guarantee they are never moved in the process. This is what is necessary to ensure a concise algorithm with consistent results. This may be improved in the future, but it's not something very critical